# How to properly use an Union with IQueryable into an one-to-one relationship with linq2db?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq2db

My regular SELECT works fine. But when I use a UNION clause, it only works if I am not using the relationship.

I'm getting some exceptions depending on the way I am doing the SELECT

I am using linq2db fluent mapping with SqlServer. Here are the mapped objects.

```
var mappingBuilder = dataConnection.MappingSchema.GetFluentMappingBuilder();

//Product
EntityMappingBuilder<Product> productBuilder = mappingBuilder.Entity<Product>();
productBuilder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsPrimaryKey().IsIdentity();
productBuilder.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
productBuilder.Property(x => x.Category).HasAttribute(new AssociationAttribute { ThisKey = "IdCategory", OtherKey = "Id", CanBeNull = true });
productBuilder.Property(x => x.Store).HasAttribute(new AssociationAttribute { ThisKey = "IdStore", OtherKey = "Id", CanBeNull = true });
productBuilder.Property(x => x.MainImageReference).HasColumnName("MainImageReference");
productBuilder.Property(x => x.Price).HasColumnName("Price");
productBuilder.Property(x => x.Brand).HasColumnName("Brand");
productBuilder.Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
productBuilder.Property(x => x.Active).HasColumnName("Active");
productBuilder.Property(x => x.IsTransient).IsNotColumn();

//Store
EntityMappingBuilder<Store> storeBuilder = mappingBuilder.Entity<Store>();
storeBuilder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsPrimaryKey().IsIdentity();
storeBuilder.Property(x => x.Address).HasAttribute(new AssociationAttribute { ThisKey = "IdAddress", OtherKey = "Id", CanBeNull = true });
storeBuilder.Property(x => x.IsTransient).IsNotColumn();

//Category
EntityMappingBuilder<Category> categoryBuilder = mappingBuilder.Entity<Category>();
categoryBuilder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsPrimaryKey().IsIdentity();
categoryBuilder.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
categoryBuilder.Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
categoryBuilder.Property(x => x.Level).HasColumnName("Level");
categoryBuilder.Property(x => x.IdParent).HasColumnName("Parent");
categoryBuilder.Property(x => x.ParentCategory).HasAttribute(new AssociationAttribute { ThisKey = "IdParent", OtherKey = "Id", CanBeNull = true });
categoryBuilder.Property(x => x.IsTransient).IsNotColumn();
```

I have a GenericGet method, where I basically get Product with their relationships and return the IQueryable with some filters. That IQueryable works fine when I am just, based on my filters, return some Products. Usually using FirstOrDefaultAsync(), .ToListAsync(), and .CountAsync().

```
private IQueryable<Product> GenericGet(parameters)
{
    var products = from p in _dataConnection.GetConnection().GetTable<Product>()
                                   .LoadWith(x => x.Category)
                                   .LoadWith(x => x.Category.ParentCategory)
                                   .LoadWith(x => x.Category.ParentCategory.ParentCategory)
                                   .LoadWith(x => x.Category.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory)
                                   .LoadWith(x => x.Category.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory)
                                   .LoadWith(x =>x.Category.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory)
                                   .LoadWith(x => x.Category.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory)
                                   .LoadWith(x => x.Category.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategory)
                                   .LoadWith(s => s.Store)
                   select p;
    // Filters 
    // various checks only in products, based on the parameters
    if (id != null && id != 0)
    {
        products = from p in products
                   where p.Id == id
                   select p;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    return products;
}
```

But one specific method uses a UNION clause to get various IQueryables and then returns all of them together.
The exception occurs in this specific method that uses UNION.
I tried some things with different outcomes.

Case 1 - Original Method

```
private IQueryable<Product> GenericMultipleGet(IEnumerable<ProductFilterModel> productFilters, int? maxItems = null)
{
    IQueryable<Product> products = null;

    foreach (var filter in productFilters)
    {
        var productList = GenericGet(null, filter.Search, null, null, null, filter.Category, filter.Brand, VisibilityType.Active);
        if (maxItems != null)
        {
            productList = productList.Take(maxItems.Value);
        }
                            
        if (products == null)
        {
            products = productList;
        }
        else
        {
            // Exception Here
            products = products.Union(productList);
        }
    }
    
    return products;
}
```

Exception

```
Exception message: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')"
Stack trace: "   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException()\r\n   at LinqToDB.SqlQuery.SqlStatement.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<PrepareQueryAndAliases>b__0(IQueryElement expr)\r\n   at LinqToDB.SqlQuery.QueryVisitor.Visit2(IQueryElement element)\r\n   at LinqToDB.SqlQuery.QueryVisitor.Visit2X(SelectQuery q)\r\n   at LinqToDB.SqlQuery.QueryVisitor.Visit2(IQueryElement element)\r\n   at LinqToDB.SqlQuery.QueryVisitor.Visit2(IQueryElement element)\r\n   at LinqToDB.SqlQuery.QueryVisitor.VisitAll(IQueryElement element, Action`1 action)\r\n   at LinqToDB.SqlQuery.SqlStatement.PrepareQueryAndAliases()\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.FinalizeQuery(Query query)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.GetExecuteQuery[T](Query query, Func`8 queryFunc)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.SetRunQuery[T](Query`1 query, Expression`1 expression)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.SetRunQuery[T](Query`1 query, Expression`1 expression)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SetOperationBuilder.SetOperationContext.BuildQuery[T](Query`1 query, ParameterExpression queryParameter)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.Build[T]()\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.CreateQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression expr)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.GetQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression& expr)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.GetQuery(Expression& expression, Boolean cache)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.<GetForEachAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at LinqToDB.AsyncExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__8`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at StoreAggregator.Api.Data.Repository.ProductRepository.<GetMultiple>d__11.MoveNext() in E:\\Projetos\\Store Aggregator\\store-aggregator-api\\StoreAggregatorApi\\StoreAggregator.Api.Repository\\Repository\\ProductRepository.cs:line 228\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at StoreAggregator.Api.Services.Products.SimilarProduct.<GetSimiliar>d__4.MoveNext() in E:\\Projetos\\Store Aggregator\\store-aggregator-api\\StoreAggregatorApi\\StoreAggregator.Api.Services\\Products\\SimilarProduct.cs:line 26\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at StoreAggregator.Api.Controllers.ProductController.<GetSimilarProduct>d__7.MoveNext() in E:\\Projetos\\Store Aggregator\\store-aggregator-api\\StoreAggregatorApi\\StoreAggregator.Api\\Controllers\\ProductController.cs:line 67\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0>d.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0>d.MoveNext()"
```

Case 2 - Construct the object by myself

```
private IQueryable<Product> GenericMultipleGet(IEnumerable<ProductFilterModel> productFilters, int? maxItems = null)
{
    IQueryable<Product> products = null;

    foreach (var filter in productFilters)
    {
        var productListGeneric = GenericGet(null, filter.Search, null, null, null, filter.Category, filter.Brand, VisibilityType.Active);
        var productList =  from p in productListGeneric
                                     select new Product
                                     {
                                            Active = p.Active,
                                            Brand = p.Brand,
                                            CreationDate = p.CreationDate,
                                            Description = p.Description,
                                            Id = p.Id,
                                            IdCategory = p.IdCategory,
                                            IdStore = p.IdStore,
                                            LastModification = p.LastModification,
                                            MainImageReference = p.MainImageReference,
                                            Price = p.Price,
                                            Name = p.Name,
                                            // The Exception occur if I included this line
                                            Store = p.Store
                                     };

        if (maxItems != null)
        {
            productList = productList.Take(maxItems.Value);
        }
                            
        if (products == null)
        {
            products = productList;
        }
        else
        {
            // Exception: "Types in Union are constructed incompatibly."
            products = products.Union(productList);
        }
    }
    
    return products;
}
```

Even if I do something like that, I'm getting the same error

```
 var productList =  from p in productListGeneric
                              select new Product
                                   {
                                       Active = p.Active,
                                       Brand = p.Brand,
                                       CreationDate = p.CreationDate,
                                       Description = p.Description,
                                       Id = p.Id,
                                       IdCategory = p.IdCategory,
                                       IdStore = p.IdStore,
                                       LastModification = p.LastModification,
                                       MainImageReference = p.MainImageReference,
                                       Price = p.Price,
                                       Name = p.Name,
                                       // The Exception occur if I included this line
                                       Store = new Store { Id = 12, Name = "Test"}
                                   };
```

Exception

```
Exception message: "Types in Union are constructed incompatibly."
Stack trace: "   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SetOperationBuilder.SetOperationContext.Init()\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SetOperationBuilder.SetOperationContext..ctor(SubQueryContext sequence1, SubQueryContext sequence2, MethodCallExpression methodCall)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SetOperationBuilder.BuildMethodCall(ExpressionBuilder builder, MethodCallExpression methodCall, BuildInfo buildInfo)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.MethodCallBuilder.BuildSequence(ExpressionBuilder builder, BuildInfo buildInfo)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildSequence(BuildInfo buildInfo)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.Build[T]()\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.CreateQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression expr)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.GetQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression& expr)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.GetQuery(Expression& expression, Boolean cache)\r\n   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.<GetForEachAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at LinqToDB.AsyncExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__8`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at StoreAggregator.Api.Data.Repository.ProductRepository.<GetMultiple>d__11.MoveNext() in E:\\Projetos\\Store Aggregator\\store-aggregator-api\\StoreAggregatorApi\\StoreAggregator.Api.Repository\\Repository\\ProductRepository.cs:line 247\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at StoreAggregator.Api.Services.Products.SimilarProduct.<GetSimiliar>d__4.MoveNext() in E:\\Projetos\\Store Aggregator\\store-aggregator-api\\StoreAggregatorApi\\StoreAggregator.Api.Services\\Products\\SimilarProduct.cs:line 26\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at StoreAggregator.Api.Controllers.ProductController.<GetSimilarProduct>d__7.MoveNext() in E:\\Projetos\\Store Aggregator\\store-aggregator-api\\StoreAggregatorApi\\StoreAggregator.Api\\Controllers\\ProductController.cs:line 67\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0>d.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0>d.MoveNext()"
```

Case 3 - Without any relationships works fine.

```
var productListGeneric = GenericGet(null, filter.Search, null, null, null, filter.Category, filter.Brand, VisibilityType.Active);
var productList =  from p in productListGeneric
                   select new Product
                   {
                       Active = p.Active,
                       Brand = p.Brand,
                       CreationDate = p.CreationDate,
                       Description = p.Description,
                       Id = p.Id,
                       IdCategory = p.IdCategory,
                       IdStore = p.IdStore,
                       LastModification = p.LastModification,
                       MainImageReference = p.MainImageReference,
                       Price = p.Price,
                       Name = p.Name
                   };
```

Is this a limitation of the UNION clause with linq2db, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is hard to understand what happened here without looking at `GenericGet` function. Probably `Store` property is not properly mapped in query. If you can create simple reproducible case - please report issue in linq2db's Github repository.

Comment: I added an issue in the linq2db github page.https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/2511

And I am updating that question with more detailed information